# same offset in a shared-type uniform buffer object in OpenGL for 4 different floats

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently programming a phong spot-light shader that uses the new ogl3 feature, ubos. My buffer object in the shader is :

`

```
Uniform Light {
   vec3 origin; 
   vec3 color; 
   vec3 direction;
   float intensity; 
   float linear_dissipation; 
   float illu_angle; 
   float max_illu_angle;
} Light[8];
```

`

When I calculate the various offsets via the function

> glGetActiveUniformsiv()

my program returns

```
origin : 0
color : 16
intensity : 48
direction : 32
illu_angle : 48
max_illu_angle : 48
linear_dissipation : 48
```

I can't use my intensity, illu_angle, max_illu_angle and linear_dissipation variables (well, only one of them :D ).

Comment: Can you show us what the layout type for the buffer object is (std140, shared, packed)? Also, what is your driver version and graphics card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `origin`, `color`, and `direction` are all aligned on 16 bytes, I assume that OpenGL is combining the last four floats into a single `vec4`.

Did you actually try using one of them to verify that they are or are not aliased?

Comment: The values inside them are unusable, they all are set to 0. I'm gonna try to put the values inside a vec4